# Does XCode take a snapshot of my app when submitting?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, restore, snapshot

After submitting an app, is there a snapshot I can revert to? I made a lot of changes, and it would just be easier to revert back, but I did not manually take a snapshot.

cheers.bo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at Apple's documentation:
**Xcode 4 creates a snapshot automatically before a major change such as refactoring your code or executing a find-and-replace operation.**
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/Xcode4TransitionGuide/SCM/SCM.html
The options can be found here: **Choose File > Project Settings (or Workspace Settings) to change this option.**
Otherwise, though, you have to manually take the snap shot.

Answer (score 2):

XCode has direct support for GIT, which is a code versioning system.
Check out Apple [XCode git docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/SCM/SCM.html).
Also, it might be worth while reading about [git basics](http://cworth.org/hgbook-git/tour/).